# getting an error when try to retrieve datagridview column value "15 digits"

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am trying to code an accounting system into which I should enter a product id, product name and product price.  After that it should be stored in a .accdb file

My problem is when I enter more than 10 digits into product id the datagridview gives me an error saying that the value is too large for int32 type.

**Error**:

> Additional information: Value was either too large or too small for an
>   Int32.Couldn't store <6221060003181> in Item_Code Column.  Expected
>   type is Int32.

When I open the accdb file, I found the data stored; but next time I open the form, it gives me that error!

```
public partial class Productentry : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{

    public OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

    public Productentry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Sama_Software\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\DB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=**************";
    }

    private void Productentry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewData();
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dBDataSet.Product' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.productTableAdapter1.Fill(this.dBDataSet.Product);


        ViewData();
    }
    void ViewData()
    {

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Product]",connection);
        da.Fill(this.dBDataSet.Product);

    }
    private void bunifuButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void bunifuButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO [Product] (Item_Code, Item_Name, Price) VALUES ('" + Pidn.Text + "','" + name.Text + "','" + price.Text + "')", connection);
        da.Fill(dBDataSet)
        ViewData();
        Pidn.Clear();
        name.Clear();
        price.Clear();
    }

    private void Cat_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bunifuButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE [Product] WHERE [Item_Code]=" + Pidn.Text + " SET [Item_Name]='" + name.Text + "',[Price]=" + price.Text + "", connection);
        da.Fill(dBDataSet);
        ViewData();
        Pidn.Clear();
        name.Clear();
        price.Clear();
    }

    private void bunifuButton4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    private void Pid_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You must have a macro in the access database that automatically runs when you open the database that reports an error.  Still the number is larger than an int32 (4 bytes).   either you have to make the column a long or treat the number as a string.,

Comment: First, if it is a product ID, why are you 'setting' or passing anything at all?  It is the job of the DB to assign unique IDs. Second, a long int would be more appropriate if not AutoNumber.   Then, never glue data with strings to make a query; it has been the wrong way for a very very long time - it isnt just old style, it is **dangerous** and error prone  Always use DB Parameters.

Comment: the id i am talking about is a barcode consists of 13 to 15 number and i am trying to store these barecodes in a form of an integer but as i shown before this error come to me

Comment: `saying that the value is too large for int32 type` The error is correct - an integer has a max limit of `2,147,483,647` or 10 digits.  So it is a poor choice for the barcode - use a long/int64.  The rest still applies.

Comment: how can i do it , i still new to c#

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp how can i use long/int64 ??

Answer (score 0):

Store the barcode as text.

Even though it is build by digits, it is not a number but a code of fixed length, and it may even have a leading zero.

Comment: i tried to do that by modifying the design of the accdb file but the error still the same !

Comment: So, did you succeed?